# Include HTML in JavaScript (.js) File

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, browser

HTML

```
<?php $var = 1; include('PHP/NavigationBar.php'); ?>
```

Navigation.php

```
<div class="sidenav">

    <h5>JavaScript</h5>

    <button class="w3-button w3-theme w3-block w3-left-align w3-padding-small"
    onclick="myAccFunc('1')"> Main Heading <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>

      <div id="1" class="w3-blue w3-hide w3-card" >
        <a class="<?php echo (($var==1)?'active':'');?>" href="Page1.php">Page 1</a>
        <a class="<?php echo (($var==2)?'active':'');?>" href="Page2.php">Page 2</a>
        <a class="<?php echo (($var==3)?'active':'');?>" href="Page3.php">Page 3</a>
        <a class="<?php echo (($var==4)?'active':'');?>" href="Page4.php">Page 4</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Navigation Menu. Currently with just 4 items and the Class="Active" represents the active Page
So if the user is on page 2, the page 2 on the Nav will be highlighted with that Class

This works completely fine but i have to shift from PHP to JavaScript

So the HTML Line becomes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="PHP/Navigation.js"></script>
```

I can get the current URL by **window.location.href**
How do i pass this to the JS File and How do i include the HTML Contents in a JS File (Currently PHP File)?

I have put all the Weblinks in an Array in the JS file. So what do i do next to achieve the same thing i achieved using PHP and HTML but with JavaScript and HTML.

**I just need to Import the Nav Menu and Highlight the Current Site using JavaScript**

Comment: keep extension of file to `php` only and include like `<script type="text/javascript" src="PHP/Navigation.php"></script>
`

Comment: Getting this Error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' @RonakDhoot

Comment: could you please share your `Navigation.js` and `NavigationBar.php` files

Comment: Navigation.php is there in the question. There is nothing in my Navigation.js yet. I just want to convert my Navigation.oho file into JavaScript where all its contents are written in JS @RonakDhoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me time to understand your expectations but now here is your `Navigation.js`

```
var activeClass = new Array(4);
if(window.location.href.includes('Page1.php')) {
    activeClass[0] = 'active';
} else if(window.location.href.includes('Page2.php')) {
    activeClass[1] = 'active';
} else if(window.location.href.includes('Page3.php')) {
    activeClass[2] = 'active';
} else if(window.location.href.includes('Page4.php')) {
    activeClass[3] = 'active';
} 
document.write('<div class="sidenav"><h5>JavaScript</h5>'+
    '<button class="w3-button w3-theme w3-block w3-left-align w3-padding-small" onclick="myAccFunc(1)">'+
    ' Main Heading <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button><div id="1" class="w3-blue w3-hide w3-card" >');
document.write('<a class="'+activeClass[0]+'" href="Page1.php">Page 1</a>');
document.write('<a class="'+activeClass[1]+'" href="Page2.php">Page 2</a>');
document.write('<a class="'+activeClass[2]+'" href="Page3.php">Page 3</a>');
document.write('<a class="'+activeClass[3]+'" href="Page4.php">Page 4</a>');
document.write('</div></div>');
```

Comment: Hold on let me check

Comment: Man! Thank you so very much..
Just another question if you dont mind. When i included this in script in my html. My other script stopped working. Do you know how to get over this?

Comment: Error that the other class contents are not found

Comment: path and filename exists ?

Comment: Yes. If i remove this JS file it works fine. i searched online and found that there would be problems if 2 scripts are included and i need to set them in proper order for it to work fine